# I have error when try run mysql server

Tags: mysql, cpanel

I have a vps with cpanel
and I have error when I try start de mysql server

ERROR! MySQL is not running, but lock file (/var/lock/subsys/mysql) exists

```
root@goldtec [~]# service mysql restart
 ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!
Starting MySQL.. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/var/lib/mysql/goldtec.net.pid).
```

I don't wanna lost the data

Comment: check the daemon has permissions to write /var/lib/mysql/goldtec.net.pid

Comment: and remove the lock file /var/lock/subsys/mysql

Comment: I don't have the file goldtec.net.pid here /var/lib/mysql/goldtec.net.pid neither mysql.sock

Comment: The file is to be created by the daemon. Just check the daemon has write permissions to write that file in that folder (it's not just about fs permissions but also selinux policy, if you have it enabled). Anyway this question is better asked on superuser.com or serverfault.com, not here. This is strictly for programming related questions and that means not so many people here can/want to help you.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issues with you my.cnf file. I will suggest you please check your MySQL error logs file, With that logs you can find out the root cause of your issues